# FASM не присваивает значение регистру bx

Tags: ассемблер, dos, x86

Просто отказывается присваивать адекватное значение регистру `mov bx,10` и как следствие выполнять адекватно проверку `cmp [flagsteps],bx` . Даже если изменить значение `flagsteps DW 0` на что то другое то он пойдет по ветке `else`.
Вот полный код.

```
    use16    
 org 100h  
    steps DW 6
    i DW 1
    a DW 0
    aold DW ?
    b DW 1
    endnumber DW 10
    answer DW 0
    flagsteps DW 0
mov bx,10
cmp [flagsteps],bx
JL if0
jmp if0cmp
if0:
do0:
    mov bx,[steps]
    cmp [i],bx
    JL do0cmp
    jmp do0exit
do0cmp:
    mov bx,[a]
    mov [aold],bx
    mov bx,[b]
    mov [a],bx
    add ax,[b]
    add ax,[aold]
    mov [b],ax
    mov ax,0
    add ax,[i]
    add ax,1
    mov [i],ax
    mov ax,0
    jmp do0
do0exit:
    mov bx,[b]
    mov [answer],bx
if0cmp:
do1:
    mov bx,[endnumber]
    cmp [b],bx
    JL do1cmp
    jmp do1exit
do1cmp:
    mov bx,[a]
    mov [aold],bx
    mov bx,[b]
    mov [a],bx
    add ax,[aold]
    add ax,[b]
    mov [b],ax
    mov ax,0
    add ax,[i]
    add ax,1
    mov [i],ax
    mov ax,0
    jmp do1
do1exit:
    mov bx,[endnumber]
    cmp [b],bx
    JG iff1
    jmp if1cmp
iff1:
    mov bx,[a]
    mov [answer],bx
    mov bx,[b]
    mov [answer],bx
if1cmp:



   mov   ax,[answer]
   xor   cx,cx
   mov   bx,10

lp1:
   xor   dx,dx
   div   bx
   add   dl,'0'
   push  dx
   inc   cx
   or    ax,ax
   jnz   lp1

lp2:
   pop   ax
   int   29h
   loop  lp2


mov ah,01h

mov AH, 4Ch
int 21h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исполнение начинается не с `mov bx,10`, а с `steps DW 6`. Именно, процессор видит эту программу так:

```
00000100  06             push es
00000101  00 01          add [bx+di],al
00000103  00 00          add [bx+si],al
00000105  00 00          add [bx+si],al
00000107  00 01          add [bx+di],al
00000109  00 0A          add [bp+si],cl
0000010B  00 00          add [bx+si],al
0000010D  00 00          add [bx+si],al
0000010F  00 BB 0A 00    add [bp+di+0xa],bh
00000113  39 1E 0E 01    cmp [0x10e],bx
```

В этом коде инструкция `00 BB 0A 00`, т.е. `add [bp+di+0xa],bh` — это смесь второго байта из `flagsteps DW 0` и всей инструкции `mov bx,10` (которая кодируется как `BB 0A 00`). Поэтому да, код действительно не присваивает регистру `bx` никакого значения перед сравнением.

Имеет смысл перенести переменные куда-нибудь в такое место, которое не будет восприниматься процессором как код — например, в конец программы.

Comment: Ну почему не работает понятно, а как это исправить не подскажите пожалуйста?Что мне нужно сделать чтобы он заработал как надо?Мне интересно как сделать так, чтобы он просто присвоил регистру число фиксированное, а после сравнил со значением переменной.

Comment: @AndreiSever в конце ответа я предложил, как можно исправить.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое!